# On OpenGL, is there any way to update a texture at specific locations?

Tags: c, opengl

On the CPU, I have an array of positions and colors:

```
[ x0, y0, z0, col0, x1, y1, z1, col1 ...]
```

On the device, I have a 3D texture. Is there any efficient way to modify that texture so that position `x0, y0, z0`'s color becomes col0 and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glTexSubimage3d will work if you can arrange your data into cubes. Doing it one texel at a time would be miserable though.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexSubImage3D.xml